# How do I catch an AuthenticationFailedException error in Java?

Tags: java, email, gmail

How would I prevent my program from crashing but instead, catch the error if I enter in wrong credentials when I am trying to send an email?

Error Code: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Comment: Please add your code in question to be more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a try, catch and resolve what should happen, if the exception gets caught in the catch phrase.

try {
`your code you want to execute`
}
catch(AuthenticationFailedException ex)
{
`what shall happen if the exception get's thrown`
}